# Static class / Object? How to dispose

Tags: c#

i'm really struggeling with OOP. I would like to start a process in my additional class. The process is a shell and I need to access this shell from severel forms and classes to write the commands and to receive the output. I use events to get the data. Here is my class for the process.

My class for the

```
public class ADBShell 
{

    public static string output = String.Empty;
    public static Process adbshell = new Process();



    public void Start_ADBShell()
    {
        if (adbshell != null && !adbshell.HasExited)
            return;

        adbshell = new Process();
        adbshell.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        adbshell.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\adb\adb.exe";
        adbshell.StartInfo.Arguments = "shell";
        adbshell.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        adbshell.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        //adb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        adbshell.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        adbshell.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //adb.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(adb_ErrorDataReceived);
        adbshell.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(adbshell_OutputDataReceived);


        try { var started = adbshell.Start(); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
        }

        //adb.BeginErrorReadLine();
        adbshell.BeginOutputReadLine();

    }

    void adbshell_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        output += (e.Data) + Environment.NewLine;

    }

   public void press_touch(string x, string y)
    {
        adbshell.StandardInput.WriteLine("input tap " + String.Format("{0} {1}", x, y));
        Debug.WriteLine("pressed");
    }
```

}

My Form class looks like

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        private bool _record;
        private bool _selecting;

        private Rectangle _selection;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  ADBShell adbshell = new ADBShell();
  adbshell.Start_ADBShell();

}
```

Everytime I have to make a new object in my methods, but i dont want to create everytime a new object. I would like make one time the object and access everytime to the same object. I do not want to make servel processes. I need only proccess and send and receive everytime the data to this process.

1. Do I have to make a static class?
2. How I can dispose and close my process after I'm quit my Form Class?

Comment: 1. No, just pass along the object. 2. Dispose the `Process` when you dispose your form.

Comment: Here's your singleton - `public class ADBShell { private static ADBShell Instance { get; } = new ADBShell(); private ADBShell() { } }`

Answer (score 2):

1: You do not want a static class. You want a SINGLETON - that is a class that has only one instance. This is normally accessed using a static property. At the easiest way this works like this:

```
public class A () {
private A () {}

public static A Instance {get; } = new A();
}
```

Access is via:

```
A.Instance
```

2: You do not. Processes do not get disposed. You exit the last thread that is not a background thread then the process ends. Otherwise you kill it, if that has to be done "In force" from the outside.

Comment: I'd also recommend reading an article on singletons by Jon Skeet: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Thank you for fast response. I will try with Singleton, but first I have to read some examples and guides about singleton.

Comment: @TomTom  Why are you saying process does not get Disposed. If I understand correctly by Dispose it means to release resource held by process. Process class has Close method and according to MSDN it free resources associated with Process.

Comment: Closing an external process can be brutal or not - the semantics are quite "open for discussion" depending what runs in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Move the ADBShell intialization in constructor of Form class. So this object will live till Form is not exited and to release resources by process make sure you call Process.close() in ADBShell class (Either in destructor or implement a IDisposable)

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            private bool _record;
            private bool _selecting;
        ADBShell adbshell;
            private Rectangle _selection;

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                adbshell = new ADBShell();
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

      adbshell.Start_ADBShell();

    }
```

Dipose Process like this by adding Destructor

```
~ADBShell()
{
   process.Close();
}
```

or implement Dispose method of IDisposable

```
Class ABDShell : IDisposable
{
  ...
  ...
 public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) 
        {
           process.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Updated singleton class

```
sealed class ADBShell 
{

    public static string output = String.Empty;

    private ABDShell _instance;
    private Process _processInstance;

     // Note: constructor is 'private'

    private ADBShell()
    {


    }

    public Process ProcessInstance
     {
          if(_processInstance==null)
           _processInstance = new Process();
           get _processInstance ;
     }

    public static ADBShell Instance
    {
        get
        {

            if (_instance == null)
            {

                _instance = new ABDShell();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Now from your Form just do this

```
Process process = ABDShell.Instance.ProcessInstance;
```

Comment: If I went this way, then the process is unkown in my other class. Means I cannot use my methods in the other class, because the object is unkown.

Comment: @Shazter I understood by your 2nd question that you need seperate instance of Process class for each Form...If that not the case then other answer where it is mentioned to use singleton pattern way to go....

Comment: Ok, now I understood. I make a singleton class and i will use the Interface IDisposable to end the process after close of my main application

Comment: I tried to make my singleton, but something i do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sealed class makes sure it is not inherited. If inheritance required, go to Abstract Pattern.
class ADBShell
{
    //public static property used to expose Singleton instance.
    public static ADBShell Instance;



    // private constructor
    private ADBShell() { }

    public static ADBShell getInstance()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = new Process;
        }
    }

}
```

**Update**

Thank you with your helps I solved my problems and now the ADB runs much faster instead of start everytime a new process.

```
public class ADBShell
{
    private static ADBShell instance;
    //private List<Employee> employeeList = null;
    private Process shell = null;
    private StreamWriter myWriter = null;
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    private ADBShell()
    {
        if (shell == null)
        {
            shell = new Process();
            shell.StartInfo.FileName = (@"D:\ADB\ADB.exe");
            shell.StartInfo.Arguments = "shell";
            shell.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            shell.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            shell.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            shell.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            shell.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            shell.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            shell.OutputDataReceived += (sender, a) => Console.WriteLine(a.Data);
            shell.Start();
            myWriter = shell.StandardInput;
            shell.BeginOutputReadLine();



        }
    }

    public static ADBShell Instance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new ADBShell();
                }

            }



        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void tap(int x, int y)
    {
        myWriter.WriteLine("input tap {0} {1}", x.ToString(), y.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    public void tap(string x, string y)
    {
        myWriter.WriteLine("input tap {0} {1}", x, y);
        Thread.Sleep(10);

    }

    public void exit()
    {
        myWriter.WriteLine("exit");

    }
    public void Close()
    {
        myWriter.WriteLine("exit");
        shell.WaitForExit();
        if (!shell.HasExited)
        {
            shell.Kill();
        }


        shell.Close();
        shell.Dispose();
        myWriter.Close();
        myWriter.Dispose();
    }
 }
```

Comment: If i try like this then i get a error, that is not possible to convert Process to ADBShell. I guess i did not understand well the singleton, maybe someone has a short hint

Comment: Please stop answering your question like this. Edit your question.